# PHP log will not ignore repeated errors with ignore_repeated_errors = On

Tags: php, directive, error-logging

Although I have instructed php to only log an error once - i see the error over and over again in my log file.  Any ideas why this directive would get ignored?  I've restarted apache, etc.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Are you certain you're editing the right php.ini file?  Look in phpinfo() to make sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This directive will only stop the error from being logged again *within the same script run*. When the same script is run multiple times, you will still see that error every time.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense thanks.  Do you know if there is anyway to make it not re-record the error every time the script is run?  I suppose I could put together a cron-job to clean it up ocassionally...

Comment: @sciguy14 Sorry for digging up such an old thread .. but have you found any solution to this issue? Did you switch over to a cron-job?

Comment: @GeneSys - I think I added what you need in new reply below

Comment: @userfuser Great. Thanks for answering old questions too :)

Answer (score 5):

Besides the `ignore_repeated_errors`, there is also the `ignore_repeated_source` ini settings. I think that one would work for you and should stop showing the same error repeatedly, when same file is called over and over.

As PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-repeated-source) says for it:

> `ignore_repeated_source` - Ignore source of message when ignoring repeated messages. When this
>   setting is On you will not log errors with repeated messages from
>   different files or sourcelines