# php-error.log reports the same error multiple times

Tags: php

php-error.log keeps reporting the same error multiple times. Seems like with every browser request. Caching is disabled on most pages as this is a dynamic site with user-generated content.

In php.ini, both ignore_repeated_errors and ignore_repeated_source are On.

Does anybody have any ideas to fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP log will not ignore repeated errors with ignore_repeated_errors = On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964732/php-log-will-not-ignore-repeated-errors-with-ignore-repeated-errors-on) - It will happen per script execution (so normally yes...per request).  How are you running PHP (mod_php, fastcgi,...)?  The best option would be to filter the log afterwards, but if you really want to get in there earlier you could use something like a cache that's passed through with the error message and only logged if there's a cache miss.

Or if you're running a typical LAMP stack you could use a db table for logging and only insert the new line if a recent one doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Matt, php is run as an apache module.Your solution is too complicated for me :) Am thinking to just clear the errors with a cron job. Looking for the clear/empty equivalent for:

    find /home -name error_log

Comment: you could use the -exec flag on error_log to clear it out with something like "echo "" > {} \;" or whatever the syntax is.  If you're feeling ambitious you could also use something like a combination of awk and uniq to merge adjacent repeated messages and then overwrite the file there.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work for me:find /home -name error_log -exec echo "" > {} \; // Any way to combine the cat /dev/null > /home with the find command ? // Basically I need to search the home dir for error_log files then clear them,Thanks a lot for your help