# ignore_repeated_errors = on, still registering the same error to the log file

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

This is an error logger:

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){

    $DateFormat = "d-m-Y G:i:s"; 
    $time = date($DateFormat);

  switch ($errno) {

      case E_ERROR:
      case E_USER_ERROR:
      case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
      error_log("$time: FATAL ERROR: $errstr in file $errfile on line: $errline \n", 1, ADMIN_EMAIL);
      error_log("$time: FATAL ERROR: $errstr in file $errfile on line: $errline \n", 3, LOG_FILE);
      break;

        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
        error_log("$time: WARNING: error $errstr in file $errfile on line:$errline \n", 3, LOG_FILE);
        break;

         case E_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
        case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
            error_log("$time: FATAL error $errstr at $errfile:$errline \n", 3, LOG_FILE);
            break;
    default:
      // Write the error to our log file
      error_log("$time Unknown error [#$errno]: $errstr in $errfile on line $errline \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);
      break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

and this code below to see how the above function work

```
set_error_handler("error_handler");
echo $hi;
```

The $hi is a variable left undefined intentionally to trigger an error. The function up top logs the error to the errors.log file somewhat like this

```
08-10-2017 12:51:27 Unknown error [#8]: Undefined variable: hi in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\index.php on line 97
```

Well done.

Problem is I would like to log the error only once so that I do not have 100 or 1000 lines of same error repeating over and over again.

I thought I found solution and adding this

```
log_errors = On
ignore_repeated_errors = On
ignore_repeated_source = On
```

to php.ini file will stop the script from logging the same error from the same file over and over again.

But no it did not help. Can you point out?

P.S. I know there is a question [PHP log will not ignore repeated errors with ignore_repeated_errors = On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964732/php-log-will-not-ignore-repeated-errors-with-ignore-repeated-errors-on) already on stackoverflow but this too does not help.

Comment: Why would one want to do that? Error, Warnings and the like should be _fixed_, not _suppressed_...

Comment: I am not talking about suppressing errors or warning, I believe in democracy, what I want is not having my log file filled with the same error over and over and over again. I want the function to register the error only once.... but wait, come to think of it, what if I forget to fix it. Probably not a good idea. Still, do you have a solution?

Comment: The `ignore_repeated_errors` directive will only stop the error from being logged again _within the same script run_. When the same script is run multiple times, you will still see that error every time. So what is the point? You certainly should stop investing into such an attempt to suppress the valuable warnings you get and instead invest that time into fixing your code or setup. Then you log files won't get flooded anyway...

Comment: I read that ... PHP log will not ignore repeated errors with ignore_repeated_errors = On  ... Can you further elaborate how do I fix the code above to stop the flooding?

Comment: You mean you experience repeated logs of exactly the same line _in a single script run_?

Comment: no not on a single run ... and I think I'll let it be the way it is .... thanks buddy

Comment: If those are separate script runs then the system acts as intended and described. There is nothing to "fix".